# Pass LocalStorage JSON to Text File at Server

Tags: php, json, ajax, local-storage

**Objective:**
Send the JSON string that resides in localStorage to a text file at the server.

I tried using AJAX and JQuery.
[Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40345069/append-json-array-from-localstorage-to-json-file-on-server)
[Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21336996/send-data-from-localstorage-via-ajax-to-php-and-save-it-in-an-html-file/)

My code:

JAVA Script

```
function testAPI() {
                FB.api('/me?fields=id,name,email', function(response) {
                    localStorage.user_data=JSON.stringify(response);

                        $.ajax({
                                    type: "POST",
                                url: "https://vtpt.in/~ad/ignore/backend.php",
                            data: {localStorage.user_data},
                        success: function() {alert("Data Sent");}
                    });


                });
    }
```

PHP

## Below is the data retrieved from SERVER

```
<?php
    $dataObject = $_POST['data']; //Fetching all posts
    file_put_contents('user_data.txt', $dataObject , FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX );

?>
```

Comment: Edit a question and post your `PHP` code.

Comment: Post your PHP Code.

Comment: @VickyGill and ValdeirPsr

Comment: what is the error ?

Comment: @Thamaraiselvam I can not find the file user_data.txt as intended at the Server

Comment: are you sure about file permissions?

Comment: @Thamaraiselvam Does that require permissions to write files on the Server? If yes how should I proceed?

Comment: Check my answer if that really an issue

Answer (score 0):

```
$dataObject = $_POST['data']; //Fetching all posts
var_dump($_POST);//Verify you get the content
$result = file_put_contents('user_data.txt', $dataObject , FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX );
if (!$result) {
    var_dump(error_get_last());//prints last php last error
}
```

Comment: No luck. Can you please check if the Syntax(s) I have used are correct including data format that have to be Transferred. I have doubts about them. Why is it so difficult to Store a single Text file on a Server !! file_put_contents should at least create a new file, what do you say?

Comment: Here's an update,
JAVA Script: 
var data_throw= localStorage.user_data;
then in the ajax section, I did, 
data: {data_throw}...

And now as you would see, alert is given that data is sent to the Location BUT still I am not able to see the where the Data is lending.

Comment: what do you get on `var_dump($_POST)`  ?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that My server did not have PHP installed. **Installing PHP removed the issue** that I wasn't getting changes at the File System level i.e. no file was created. But works fine Now.